# SAS proc ttest or proc mixed

Tags: sas, statistics, comparison

Hey so I'm trying to do a 2 tailed t test to well I'll just post the question

Solution 1: 9.9, 10.6, 9.4, 10.3, 10.0, 9.3, 10.3, 9.8
Solution 2: 10.2, 10.6, 10.0, 10.2, 10.7, 10.4, 10.5, 10.3

(a) Do the data indicate that the claim that both solutions have the same mean etch rate is valid? Use ( alpha= 0.05 and assume equal variances. 
(b) Find a 95 percent conﬁdence interval on the difference in mean etch rates.

Here is my code.

```
data one;
input one @@;
cards;
9.9 10.6 9.4 10.3 10.0 9.3 10.3 9.8
run;



data two;
input two @@;
cards;
10.2 10.6 10.0 10.2 10.7 10.4 10.5 10.3
run;


data one_two;
set one two;
run;
```

I have tried using proc t test however I am having a hard time making the 2 diffirent data sets compare with one another I was going to use Proc Mixed data however I am not getting any output with that. So any hints or tips that can be given will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

The issue seems to with the formatting. Code

```
data one_two;
    set one two;
run;
```

Creates table like

```
one two 
1   .
1   .
.   2
.   2
.   2
```

What you want to do is merge the data row by row:

```
data one_two; 
    merge one two; 
run;

proc ttest data=one_two; 
    var one two; 
run;
```

For more about merging in SAS see [documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1i8w2bwu1fn5kn1gpxj18xttbb0.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).